# Apparently fetch returns NULL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I am learning stored procedures, cursors in mysql and I stumble on it:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE some_func()
BEGIN
    DECLARE link_rewrite VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE link_rewrite_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT link_rewrite FROM prod;

    OPEN link_rewrite_cursor;

    SET @count = 0;

    WHILE @count < 10 DO
        FETCH link_rewrite_cursor INTO link_rewrite;
        SELECT link_rewrite;
        set @count = @count + 1;
    END WHILE;

    CLOSE link_rewrite_cursor;

END//

delimiter ;
```

My question is: Why SELECT link_rewrite always returns NULL (in prod table there is 9000 rows). SELECT link_rewrite FROM prod returns a lot of rows(9000 rows).

Answer (score 22):

You should avoid using the same name for multiple different things. Specifically, give the variable a different name than the column you are selecting. For example, if you rename the variable v_link_rewrite then it will probably work:

```
delimiter //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS some_func //

CREATE PROCEDURE some_func()
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_link_rewrite VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE link_rewrite_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT link_rewrite FROM prod;

    OPEN link_rewrite_cursor;

    SET @count = 0;

    WHILE @count < 10 DO
        FETCH link_rewrite_cursor INTO v_link_rewrite;
        SELECT v_link_rewrite;
        set @count = @count + 1;
    END WHILE;

    CLOSE link_rewrite_cursor;

END//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem too. In my case I had named the variable the same as the selected alias, not the actual column name. Funny - I thought it was nice and tidy for them all to be named the same!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to select the top 10 rows, do this:

```
select link_rewrite from prod limit 10
```

It's much quicker and you don't have to go with a cursor.

Comment: @Eric It does beacuse select returns something (in this case NULL) so in my opinion it hits while loop. Yea you could do it much quicker but I am trying to learn cursors and stored procedure.

Comment: @PaulP, what does `select link_rewrite from prod limit 10` give you? If that's the case, then my guess is that you have `null` values in the table (regardless how many rows you have).

Comment: @Eric select link_rewrite from prod limit 10 returns 10 rows with values(not equal NULL)

Comment: @PaulP Does `select link_rewrite from prod where link_rewrite is null limit 10` return 10 rows? It could just be in this case the order of the results returning (rows are never returned in a guaranteed order unless an `order by` clause is specified).